# TabHost setContent Error :(

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i was try to open 2nd activity.class in tab host my android app

here is code example ..

```
TabHost th =(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
th.setup();
TabSpec ts = th.newTabSpec("Tab1");
ts.setContent(new Intent(this,SecActivity.class)) ;
ts.setIndicator("Tab Play");
th.addTab(ts);
```

when i click on tab1 my app crash :(

please tell me is this correct way to open activity in tabhost ??

this method is works fine .

```
   ts.setContent(R.id.btn2)) ;
```

problem only when i try to open new activity in tabhost 
thanks

Comment: Having activities in tabs has been deprecated for **about 3.5 years**. Please use a more modern tab approach, such as `FragmentTabHost` or a `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator (e.g., `PagerTabStrip`). Or, stick with `TabHost`, but use views for your tabs.

Comment: Anyway, have you declared SecActivity in your manifest?

Comment: YES Bro i was declared